# wrong timestamp in logstash after using "date match" rule

Tags: elasticsearch, nginx, timestamp, logstash, kibana

I have a problem with my logstash configuration. I wnat to use 'timestamp' field from nginx logs

```
match => { "message" => "%{IPORHOST:clientip} - (%{USERNAME:auth}|-) \[%{**HTTPDATE:timestamp**}\] %{INT:response} \"%{DATA:verb} %{GREEDYDATA:request} (HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})\" %{NUMBER:bytes} \"%{GREEDYDATA:referrer}\" \"%{GREEDYDATA:agent}\" \"%{GREEDYDATA}\" \"X-Real-IP (%{IPORHOST:x-real-ip}|-)\" \"Scheme %{DATA}\" \"ReqTime %{NUMBER:request_time:float}\" \"Upstream (%{HOSTPORT:upstream}|-)\""  }
```

after that i do

```
   date {
      locale => "ru"
      timezone => "Europe/Moscow"
      match => [ "timestamp", "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z"]
      target => 'timestamp'
    }
```

finally i got wrong timestamp in kibana: timestamp Jan 4, 2021 @ 19:03:05.000,
but real date is Aug 30, 2021 @ 19:03:05.000

Whats wrong?

PS. Also i have custom mapping in elasticsearch:

```
"timestamp" : {
  "type" : "date",
   "format":"dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z"
 },
```

Comment: are you sure `HTTPDATE` as the right format ? can you share an example of nginx logs lines

Comment: Yes, sure. Like this: *.*.*.*- - [30/Aug/2021:19:03:05 +0300] 200 "POST /cgi-bin/exaple.cgi HTTP/1.1" 143 "https://example.org/cgi-bin/admin/test.cgi" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0" "-" "X-Real-IP -" "Scheme https" "ReqTime 0.723" "Upstream 172.16.1.1:443" referrer:https://example.org/cgi-bin/admin/example.cgi